# How to provide AWS API Gateway Custom Authorizer a Lambda Permission?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS Lambda function, to which I am trying to provide permission after successfully setting it as an Authorizer.

**Basically I want to achieve the following in CloudFromation -**

[image]

**Following is my CloudFormation resource, which is unable to set the permission -**

```
GWAuthPermission:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName: !GetAtt AuthTest.Arn
      Principal: "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${ApiGatewayRestApi}/authorizers/${AuthTest}"
```

**ApiGatewayRestApi** - is the logical Id of the Gateway
**AuthTest** - is the logical Id of the Custom Auth lambda function

Comment: Try Serverless, It's simple than CloudFormation and it generates cloudformation template internally. https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#http-endpoints-with-custom-authorizers

Comment: @Gangaraju actually, due do multiple vendors and different developer preferences, some prefer SAM, some serverless, So Cloidformation was decided as standard for Infra setup.

Comment: You can still try serverless to generate the CloudFormation template and Copy the generated code to your project.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**I was able to resolve it with the following -**

Added `AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer` resource,
And referred it to `AWS::Lambda::Permission`

**Code -**

```
GWAuth:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
    Properties: 
      AuthorizerUri: !Sub "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${AuthLambda.Arn}/invocations"
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi
      Type: "REQUEST"
      IdentitySource: method.request.header.authorization
      Name: custom_auth

  GWAuthPermission:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName: !GetAtt AuthLambda.Arn
      Principal: "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${ApiGatewayRestApi}/authorizers/${GWAuth}"
```